# Magento 2.2 problem with .phtml overwriting using module

Tags: magento2

I want to overwrite gallery.phtml block from single product page.
Magento 2 file catalog_product_view.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.detail.info" as="product_detail_info" template="product/view/detail_layout.phtml" after="-" >           
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery" name="product.info.media.image" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/gallery.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

I want to replace gallery.phtml file. 
Here's my two method:

**1st - layout.xml method**
**catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
<referenceBlock name="product.info.media.image">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">UNBXD_ProductAttributes::catalog/product/view/gallery.phtml</argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**2nd method - di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View">
        <plugin name="custom_widget_name" type="UNBXD\ProductAttributes\Plugin\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery" />
    </type>
</config>
```

**Gallery.php**

```
<?php
namespace UNBXD\ProductAttributes\Plugin\Catalog\Block\Product\View;
class Gallery
{
    public function after_construct(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View $result)
    {

        $result->setTemplate('UNBXD_ProductAttributes::catalog/product/view/gallery.phtml');
        return $result;
    }
}
?>
```

Nothing seems to work. I know this block in nested in another block. Is referenceBlock name 'product.info.media.image' correct in this case?

Answer (score 0):

**Try This :-**

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.media.image">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">UNBXD_ProductAttributes::catalog/product/view/gallery.phtml</argument>
            </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

Comment: Still nothing:/

Comment: check your file path and after code clean cache and then try

Comment: path is correct /app/code/UNBXD/ProductAttributes/view/frontend/templates/catalog/product/view/gallery.phtml

Answer (score 0):

If I add remove='true'

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
<referenceBlock name="product.info.media.image" remove="true">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">UNBXD_ProductAttributes::catalog/product/view/gallery.phtml</argument>
            </action>
</referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

image is removed so reference name is correct but new template isn't injected....

Answer (score 0):

[image: a busy cat]

path looks ok. All cache cleaned, recompilled files ect...